# FALLO - No pude desplegar la aplicación en ruta de contexto

Tags: java, web, despliegue

Tengo un problema con mi web en Java.
Es un proyecto recién creado y el típico Hola Mundo; pero no consigo que funcione.

El error que me salta cuando le doy a Ejecutar, es el siguiente: "FALLO - No pude desplegar la aplicación en ruta de contexto"

Para más info, adjunto el log de consola resultante:

```
Deploying on Apache Tomcat or TomEE
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
In-place deployment at C:\Users\david\Documents\CursoJava\Mensajes\target\Mensajes-1.0-SNAPSHOT
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fdavid%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext497459838337451853.xml&path=/Mensajes
FALLO - No pude desplegar la aplicación en ruta de contexto [/Mensajes]
cd C:\Users\david\Documents\CursoJava\Mensajes; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19" cmd /c "\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-16\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dnetbeans.deploy=true -Dexec.vmArgs= -Dexec.appArgs= \"-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-16\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" package"
Scanning for projects...

-----------------------< com.mycompany:Mensajes >-----------------------
Building Mensajes 1.0-SNAPSHOT
--------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------

--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:copy (default) @ Mensajes ---

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Mensajes ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\david\Documents\CursoJava\Mensajes\src\main\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Mensajes ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Mensajes ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\david\Documents\CursoJava\Mensajes\src\test\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Mensajes ---
No sources to compile

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Mensajes ---

--- maven-war-plugin:3.3.2:war (default-war) @ Mensajes ---
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [Mensajes] in [C:\Users\david\Documents\CursoJava\Mensajes\target\Mensajes-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\david\Documents\CursoJava\Mensajes\src\main\webapp]
Building war: C:\Users\david\Documents\CursoJava\Mensajes\target\Mensajes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  2.975 s
Finished at: 2023-02-05T13:49:47+01:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deploying on Apache Tomcat or TomEE
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
In-place deployment at C:\Users\david\Documents\CursoJava\Mensajes\target\Mensajes-1.0-SNAPSHOT
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fdavid%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext17020685005624297088.xml&path=/Mensajes
FALLO - No pude desplegar la aplicación en ruta de contexto [/Mensajes]
```

Por si ayuda, tengo configurada la variable de entorno CATALINA_HOME:
[image: Variable de entorno CATALINA_HOME]

Y también tengo añadidas a la variable de entorno 'Path', las rutas de Tomcat y MySQL:
[image: Variable de entorno 'Path']

Por otro lado, tengo la siguiente versión de Tomcat:

[image: Versión Tomcat]

En cuanto a la config de NetBeans, tengo lo siguiente en la parte de servidores:
[image: NetBeans Config Servers]

La versión de NetBeans y Java JVM que tengo son las siguientes:
[image: Versiones NetBeans, JVM, Windows, etc.]

La verdad es que he sido toda la vida programador de .NET y ahora quería aprender Java, y voy desde cero.

He estado mirando por Internet, y pudiera ser por el fichero 'pom.xml', adjunto el código por si ayuda:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>Mensajes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Mensajes</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.27</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano a todo el mundo.

Comment: Para ir descartando has habilitado el usuario en el archivo tomcat_users.xml y asignado los roles roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script".

Comment: Hay un web.xml? Fijate si puedes subir la estructura de archivos de la aplicación.

Comment: Acabo de comprobar que tengo los siguientes roles en mi usuario en el fichero tomcat_users.xml: roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script,admin"

Comment: Si que tengo un web.xml, en la ruta: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\conf", pero no sé qué debo configurar ahí para el mensaje que me da... :(

Comment: Hola David, te recomiendo hacer el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 1):

Funcionó modificando el archivo tomcat_users.xml, como me comentaba el compañero Roberto E Moran.

Lo dejé como:

```
roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script,admin"
```

Faltaba el rol de 'admin-gui'